# set automatic android gridview column size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

Ive got some GridView with textviews inside it. Now the columns are all the same size but the problem is when the text inside some Item is longer than the column size, the text breaks into the next line. I dont want to have text in multiple lines (e.g. because the next lines cannot be seen because of heigth of the row) but I want the column to automatically adapt so the text will be in one line
these are my XMLs:
gridView in an activity

```xml
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/sensorsGrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:background="#FFCCFF99"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="6" >
```

xml for items in the GridRow

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="10dp"> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/griditem_text" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" > 
    </TextView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if one of the text strings is too long for a line? Do you want each row of the grid to have different sized columns?

Comment: thanks for your reply and no I dont want the rows to have different column sizes